# How to correctly fill the permission declaration form in the google play console?

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play-console

I have one application which used to be taking sensitive SMS permissions. But I removed them and tried to upload a new APK without those permissions. But when submitting the app we are required to choose at least one of the options from the list. But am clear that we do not have to choose any of the below options. Is there any ways to override the permission declaration form as I'm not able to find the option "I don't use any of the options above".

Here is the list of permissions. If anyone knows the correct choice for this type of app I’d appreciate the advice.

==== Permissions Choices =======

Default SMS handler

Default Phone handler

Default Assistant handler

Transactional backup and restore for users and archive for enterprise (time-limited/non-continuous)

Enterprise SMS call archives

Caller ID, spam detection, and blocking

Connected device companion apps (for example, smartwatch or automotive)

Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls

SMS-based financial transactions and related activity where access is restricted to financial SMS transactions (for example, 5-digit messages)

SMS based money management

Proxy calls

Services - Carrier

Services - OEM

Device Automation

Physical safety / emergency alert apps (e.g., senior safety)

Call-based OTP account verification

Using SMS_CB_RECEIVED for customer communications (e.g., Smart Zone Cast service)

Write and Show Call History in Dialer

Answer (score 4):

After Mar 9, 2019, The option of **No, this release does not meet the SMS and call log permissions policy**  has been gone,
and we stuck in the Declaration form that not exactly needed after we removed the sensitive permission list.

I solved that issue by the following steps:

All our work will be in "App releases" tab
[image]

1. Make sure you don't use any of the sensitive permissions for the
   last APK that you uploaded in the Google Console play
   You can check the final list of permissions by open production track or any track that has the last APK and open the required permissions:

   - click on the android app bundle
   - expand the "Required permissions"
     [image]
   - If all your APK permissions not on the list of the google sensitive permissions  [high risk or sensitive permissions](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/)  you ready to go to the next step
2. Remove all Active APKs that using the sensitive permissions from all Release tracks.

Now check all Tracks (Open track, Closed tracks, Internal test track & Pre-registration)

- Click on Manage for every track that has an Active sensitive permissions APK
- Create Release
- DON'T choose any active APK just make sure your Active sensitive permissions APK in the Retain section to be deactivated

[image]

- Choose any option from Declaration form and click review rollout
- Do the above steps with all active tracks that have active APK with sensitive APK except the Production Track.

Then for the Production track Create Release with your Latest APK (**without** sensitive APK) and you will find that Declaration form has gone.

Submit and Rollout

Answer (score 1):

The form should be submitted only if you want to keep the permission in your app. If you have removed the permission then follow the below steps.

1. Upload the APK
2. Choose **No this release does not meet the SMS and Call log permission policy**.
3. Don't choose any of the choices in the core functionality section and don't fill any thing further in the form.
4. Release the app.

Next time you won't be asked to submit the form.

> Note: you should remove the permission and you should not add it in
>   the next release.

[image]

Comment: After uploading the app the next step will be to fill out the permission declaration form. Where to find **App doesn't meet Google permission policy** option?

Comment: The problem is now I'm not able to get that option **No, this release does not meet the SMS and call log permissions policy.**. Else I could have done it that way.

Comment: Same me, not able to get that option No, this release does not meet the SMS and call log permissions policy.

Comment: Same issue as Cline Paul - the “No, this release does not meet the SMS and call log permissions policy” does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

- First try to replace your current functionality with default one and remove the permission related to particular functionality. After Upload build on play store and fill the form.
- If your functionality is preset in following list, explain properly in the form and submit it.

I have one application which used to be taking sensitive SMS permissions. But I removed them and tried to upload a new APK without those permissions. But when submitting the app we are required to choose at least one of the options from the list. But am clear that we do not have to choose any of the below options. Is there any ways to override the permission declaration form as I'm not able to find the option "I don't use any of the options above".

Here is the list of permissions. If anyone knows the correct choice for this type of app I’d appreciate the advice.

==== Permissions Choices =======

Transactional backup and restore for users and archive for enterprise (time-limited/non-continuous)

Enterprise SMS call archives

Caller ID, spam detection, and blocking

Connected device companion apps (for example, smartwatch or automotive)

Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls

SMS-based financial transactions and related activity where access is restricted to financial SMS transactions (for example, 5-digit messages)

SMS based money management

Proxy calls

Services - Carrier

Services - OEM

Device Automation

Physical safety / emergency alert apps (e.g., senior safety)

Call-based OTP account verification

Using SMS_CB_RECEIVED for customer communications (e.g., Smart Zone Cast service)

Write and Show Call History in Dialer