# Problem with previous feature of android.permission.SEND_SMS

Tags: android, sms

For the new policy of Google, I've take the decision to delete this feature to send SMS in my app. I deleted in the manifest the android.permission.SEND_SMS, and all the code about the SMS.
My problem is... I can not to update my app. Always the console ask me for which reason in my app I use the SMS feature. There is not way to resolve the problem.
Someone can help me?
Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="app.MyApp.firstrelease"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:versionCode="26"
    android:versionName="4.5">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".MyApp"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I resolve the problem using the alpha channel and then forward from alpha to prod.
So I think it is a google console error. My trick is just a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I resolved before to read your answer. I had a alpha version with the android.permission.SEND_SMS. I just updated with a new alpha version and all the requests are gone. The console in Android needs to be improved because is a really mess in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fill Permission Declaration form

Follow below step

1. Go to Google Play developer console
2. Select **Release Management**, then **App Releases**.
3. Click on **Create Release** button
4. Upload new apk which have not SMS permission
5. [IMPORTANT] Click on **RETAIN** on previous (the one that contains the SMS permissions) version - which will present the inline Permission Declaration Form.
6. In Permission Declaration Form, under Compliance status (Does this release meet the SMS and Call Log permissions policy? If you choose no, you can submit the form without selecting any core functionalities.), select No, this release does not meet the SMS and Call Log permissions policy
7. Check all check-boxes under Declarations (By submitting this Permissions Declaration Form, I confirm that).
8. Click to **Save** then **Review** button

   9. You will be navigated to Review and rollout screen, and Rollout button will be finally enabled.

In order to remove the retained version (from step 5 - the one that contains the SMS permissions), you can create another release (with an APK having higher version) - in which you'll be able to deactivate any previous version

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The step 6 there is not. I tried many time but nothing. Any suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254797/how-to-correctly-fill-the-permission-declaration-form-in-the-google-play-console

Comment: No solution. My app is been removed today. I update the new app without the permission but nothing to do.