# why always app has been rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation:

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to upload apk on playstore from few days. but now days its showing list of core functionality in deceleration form like SMS and call log.
but in our apk there is no use of such permissions. I am using Internet and Fine Location permission, but its not listed there. there is compulsion that we require to select atleast one permission.therefore I am selecting Default SMS handler.

even I search through many tools there is no SMS and call log permission is used in whole source code.

As I found many answer on google that Make sure your SMS permission is given in manifest and give the pop up in user level.

but there is no permission in my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.demmyname.com">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="com.demmyname.com.Classes.Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
         android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".Activities.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_Login" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_SignUp" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_Forgot_Pwd" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_Profile" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_Change_Password" />

        <service
            android:name=".Services.AppLocationService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_Chnage_Location" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_Order_Delivary" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_Order_PichUp" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activityz_Hotel_Categories" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_Category_Items" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_Cart_List" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_Place_Order" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_MyOrders" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_About_Us" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_View_Offer"></activity>

        <!--
            <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="7aa3cad21d26b0edcfccea540b57016907999433"
            />
        -->


        <!-- <meta-data android:name="firebase_crash_collection_enabled" android:value="false" /> -->

        <activity android:name=".Activities.Activity_PayUMoney"></activity>

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am looking for solution how to skip declaration form or without selecting core functionality.

Comment: Check the libraries you use, one of them may request the permission.

Comment: Check that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55355225/3494026

Answer (score 0):

To make sure if any other libraries are using the violated permissions, do the following...

In your Android Studio, open the manifest file and observe that in the below of the page 2 (two) Tabs are there =>

1. Text
2. Merged Manifest

Click on the Merged Manifest tab. Then search for the

> uses-permission

Check that if it contains any call log or sms permissions (or other violated permissions).

If you find any use of the violated permissions like that, add the following line in your manifest under the

> manifest tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" tools:node="remove" />
```

And for each and every violated permission add another line like the above with the appropriate permission tag.

Then rebuild the project and check that your merged manifest does not contain any violated permissions. After the confirmation generate signed APK and update your application in the Google Play console. (For now, check the do not meet the Google privacy policies in the declaration form).

After a successful update and around after 24 hours, recheck that the form (in Play console) exist or not. There should not be any form after a successful APK update.

You may want to update your APK again after the form disappears for a clear update.